# UITableView Cell takes a few taps to present view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Essentially, with the code below I have the user select on any particular row and have another ViewController shown. While this does work correctly when the app first launches, after pressing and having the ViewController present a few times successfully, so often I will have to press on the cell 2 or 3 times before the ViewController is shown.

Does this have something to do with my custom UITableViewCell class?

The following the code I am using in the `TableViewController`

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
        let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "scheduledDelivery")


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of `didSelectRowAt` do

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this other question? I'm just wondering how to pass the selected cells value to another view controller as variable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779146/how-pass-the-value-of-a-selected-cell-to-another-viewcontroller